# Artifactory REST API: How to generate Build Info json

Tags: json, jenkins, artifactory

I'm trying to generate within a build job a JSON build info file to upload to Artifactory and create a trace-ability between the two tools. However the regular Jenkins JSON API file is not in the correct design, therefore I need to generate a new one while running a job. The question is simple, how do I do that? Is there some specific plugin(tool) I need to add to Jenkins, or perhaps just a simple set of commands will do the work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/build-info-java-example) that demonstrate how to easily create and deploy a build info into Artifactory.

Comment: Ooops, we had a race condition :) I added the link to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest generating the BuildInfo JSON in a separate script, not from Jenkins itself. Jenkins will just call that script and pass all the info about the build environment (like build name, build number and other environment variables).

And here's [an example of how you can generate the BuildInfo](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/build-info-java-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Artifactory Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) .

This will do exactly what you want (If you are not using Java build tools like Maven, Gradle or Ivy use freestyle job and choose "Generic integration").

Comment: I'm aware of that option, and there is no possible way for me to use the build in plugin. I have to do it manually. Therefore the question is here.